# Qt - QLineEdit does not emit textChanged/textEdited Signal while QTextEdit does

Tags: qt

Currently i am learning Qt in C++ and have following issue: 
Connecting "textChanged" or "textEdited" with a slot does not work.

Header file:

```
#include ...

class PersonalPreferences : public QWidget
{
    Q_OBJECT

public:
    PersonalPreferences(QWidget *parent = nullptr);

public slots:
    void make_available();

private:
    ...

};
```

Code file:

```
PersonalPreferences::PersonalPreferences(QWidget *parent) {
    // Configuring Layout

    connect(line_edit_name, SIGNAL(textEdited()), this, SLOT(make_available()));
}
```

make_available function:

```
void PersonalPreferences::make_available() {
    label_name->setText("wadwad");
    group_box_pref->setEnabled(true);
    push_button_ok->setEnabled(true);
    push_button_close->setEnabled(true);

}
```

Please notice that i intentionally reduced the code to it's significant parts and didn't include the main file. I tried the same code with and without the parameter `make_available(const QString &text)`. Yet it does not change the outcome.

I also tried this

```
connect(line_edit_name, &QLineEdit::textEdited, this, &PersonalPreferences::make_available);
```

and still it did not work out.

I noticed that using `QTextEdit` instead of `QLineEdit` works, but nevertheless i need help to solve this issue with `QLineEdit`.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: can you show me the code related to the pointer line_edit_name?

Answer (score 0):

you need to study the details carefully)

In `QLineEdit`, the signal is

```
void textChanged ()
```

In `QTextEdit`, the signal is

```
void textChanged (const QString & text)
```

then you need to make such an amendment

```
void make_available()
```

change to

```
void make_available(const QString & text)
```

and call

```
connect(line_edit_name, &QLineEdit::textEdited, this, &PersonalPreferences::make_available);
```

or

```
connect(line_edit_name, SIGNAL(textEdited()), this, SLOT(make_available()));
```

change to

```
 connect(line_edit_name, SIGNAL(textEdited(QString)), this, SLOT(make_available(QString)));
```

Comment: Thank you very much!